# Can't get data return from another file React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, async-await

I'm using a external utilities file. It's just a JS file.

```
export const getUser = async () =>  {

db = SQLite.openDatabase("PegaPreco_data_src");
await db.transaction(tx => {
    tx.executeSql(
        "create table if not exists user (id text primary key not null, cpf text, nome text, " +
        "email text, senha text);"
    );
});

return await db.transaction(tx => {
    tx.executeSql("select * from user", [],
        (_, { rows }) => {
            console.log('My rowa', rows._array[0]); //console print - Ok
            return rows._array[0];
        },
        (error) => {
            console.error('Data errors \n', error);
        })
})
}
```

In my full state component i have imported de utility file and I'm trying get data:

```
componentDidMount() {
  getUser()
        .then((MyUser) => {
            console.log(MyUser); //undefined here
            this.setState({ user: MyUser });
        })
        .then(console.log('My console.log for tests', this.state.user)); always the user is undefined
...more code...
```

And I can't realise what's wrong.
The initial state is Ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with the library that you're using, but it looks like calling `db.transaction` and then `tx.executeSql` doesn't return anything, i.e. it's not a `Promise` that resolves/rejects with some value. It looks like it's callback based, therefore you'll have to do that "manually" and turn it into a `Promise`.

Here's a possible fix:

```js
// mock for the `db` library you're using
const mockDb = {
  transaction: callback => {
    callback({
      executeSql: (arg1, arg2, cb) => {
        const user = { id: 1, name: "John Doe", age: 20 };
        cb(null, user);
      }
    });
  }
};

// utils/getUser.js
const getUser = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const db = mockDb;

    db.transaction(tx => {
      tx.executeSql("...", "...", () => {});
    });

    db.transaction(tx => {
      tx.executeSql("...", [], (_, result) => {
        resolve(result);
      });
    });
  });
}

// components/MyComponent.js
getUser()
  .then(result => { console.log('result', result); })
  .catch(error => { console.error(error); })
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Because you actually need to return data from the getUser(). You can do it by using promise resolve reject

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all.
I've refactoring my code and i realized this way is working

```
export const getUser = async () => {
db = SQLite.openDatabase("PegaPreco_data_src");
return new Promise((resolve, rejected) => {

    db.transaction(tx => {
        tx.executeSql("select * from user", [], (_, { rows }) => {
            resolve(rows._array[0]);
        });
    });
})
}
```

Comment: But it is a good idea to include a code example, however simple it may be to help. It is marked

Comment: Not sure what you mean? I included a working example with explanation - see below.